# How do I convert my walkscoreAPI output list to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, rjson

I have used the walkscore API to generate output for a list of Lat and Longs

Reprex of dataset:

```
tibble::tribble(
         ~Lat,        ~Long,
  39.75454546, -82.63637088,
  40.85117794, -81.47034464,
  40.53956136, -74.33630685,
  42.16066679, -71.21368025,
  39.27048579, -119.5770782,
  64.82534285, -147.6738774
  )
```

My code:

```
library(walkscoreAPI)
library(rjson)
data = read.csv(file="geocode_finalcompiled.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
attach(data)
#create empty list
res = list()
# for loop through a file

for(i in 1:500){
  res[i] = list(getWS(data$Long[i],data$Lat[i],"mykey"))

}
```

## show results

res

```
> res
[[1]]
$status
[1] 1

$walkscore
[1] 2

$description
[1] "Car-Dependent"

$updated
[1] "2019-03-28 21:43:37.670012"

$snappedLong
[1] -82.6365

$snappedLat
[1] 39.7545
```

As you can see the output is in json format. My objective is to make this into a dataframe where each value is displayed under each header and can be put into a csv.

I tried:

> resformatted <- as.data.frame(res)

But got the below error:

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"WalkScore"’ to a data.frame

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: The output is a `list` not `json` or am I wrong? Unclass it and make it a df as required.

Comment: @NelsonGon how do you unclass it and make it as a df?

Comment: Cannot test since I don't have this package installed. Try `as.data.frame(unclass(res))`. Alternatively, what is the output of `sapply(res, class)`?

Comment: > sapply(res, class)
[1] "WalkScore" "WalkScore" "WalkScore" "WalkScore" "WalkScore" "WalkScore"

Comment: Also,   > as.data.frame(unclass(res))
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"WalkScore"’ to a data.frame

Comment: Is the sample data the data used in the `read.csv` step?

Comment: Yes the reprex I have put here is a representation of my dataset

Comment: > class(res)
[1] "list"

Comment: No API access. Try this.`as.data.frame(sapply(res, unclass))` Hopefully someone with API access helps you solve it.

Comment: > as.data.frame(sapply(res, unclass))
                                    V1                         V2
status                               1                          1
walkscore                            2                          4
description              Car-Dependent              Car-Dependent
updated     2019-03-28 21:43:37.670012 2019-04-11 11:23:51.651955
snappedLong                   -82.6365                    -81.471
snappedLat                     39.7545                     40.851

Comment: How can i get this in long format? like headers and values under them?

Comment: I cannot test, I have no data hence just giving directions. You can add the output of the above "solution" to the question so I(we) can have usable data. Also consider accepting answers to past questions if they solved your issue. Do so by clicking the tick below the answer that helped.

Comment: Can you provide the output `list` in reproducible form instead of the input dataset? How you collected the data is not really relevant to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the above approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

res %>% 
  sapply(unclass) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  lapply(unlist) %>% 
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  remove_rownames() -> df
```

Produces:

```
#   status walkscore       description                    updated snappedLong snappedLat
# 1      1         2     Car-Dependent 2019-03-28 21:43:37.670012    -82.6365    39.7545
# 2      1         4     Car-Dependent 2019-04-11 11:23:51.651955     -81.471     40.851
# 3      1        60 Somewhat Walkable 2019-02-25 01:05:08.918498     -74.337     40.539
# 4      1        44     Car-Dependent 2019-04-17 16:26:58.848496     -71.214    42.1605
# 5      1        16     Car-Dependent 2019-05-09 01:34:59.741290    -119.577      39.27
# 6      1         0     Car-Dependent 2019-07-22 19:27:50.170107   -147.6735    64.8255
```

And write to csv with:

```
write.csv(df, file = "dfwalk.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, This worked. this may sound like a basic question but when i try to allocate this script to a vector and write to a csv i get an error > write.csv(df, file = "dfwalk.csv")
Error in write.table(df, file = "dfwalk.csv", col.names = NA, sep = ",",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'. How can I write this to a csv?

Comment: See edits above. Apparently the old code did not produce a proper data.frame even though it looked like it when viewed with the print method. There is almost certainly a better way to do this, but the above works.

Comment: See re-edits that are more explicit about writing to csv.